# How to pass to class method argument of class type in python?

Tags: python-3.x, class, types

I have a class and would like to define a method that accepts an argument of the same class type like this:

```
class MyClass:

  def my_method(self, param: MyClass):
    pass
```

But I have an error `Unresolved reference 'MyClass'`

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references):

> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.

So you can put your class name inside the quotes:

```
class MyClass:
  def my_method(self, param: 'MyClass'):
    pass
```